# iOS App: How to localize the app name (for Australia English) displayed on the device?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

iOS App: How to localize the app name (for Australia English) displayed on the device? 
I know how to localize for French, German, etc.

But it seems there is no way to localize the App Name for Australia English. There is only one English localization that will be used for All English App Name, such as US, UK, Canada, Australia, etc.

Am I missing something? Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to localize those countries individually. Go to your project settings in Xcode -> click the add button -> hover over the 'Other' option -> select country-specific localization. There you go! It's that simple.

[image: Xcode Settings]